# How do I unset $_SESSION with wildcards

Tags: php, session

Example I have 100 fields of form. Each field will have error session. When form successfully submitted, I want unset any session which word begin with `$_SESSION['submit_']`

First I can do like

```
unset($_SESSION['submit_first_name'],
$_SESSION['submit_last_name'],
$_SESSION['submit_status'],
$_SESSION['submit_mobile'],
$_SESSION['submit_category']);
```

But too long.

If I do like

```
session_destroy();
```

Then will kill my log in session

Possible to unset the session word begin with **`[submit_']`**?

Let me know :)

Comment: it should be `$_SESSION['submit']['last_name']`, silly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
  if (strpos($key, 'submit_') === 0)
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

Or you can rearrange your $_SESSION variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['submit']['first_name'];
$_SESSION['submit']['last_name'];
$_SESSION['log']['some_log'];
.
.
.
unset($_SESSION['submit']);
```

Comment: I dont get it. If you want to unset all entrys with a key that starts with 'submit_' shouldn´t the condition be "if(strpos($key,'sumit_)!==FALSE)" ? -.- never mind just figured it....1 minute after posting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use wildcards, but you can list them out in one command if that helps you... Like so:

```
unset($_SESSION['submit_last_name'], $_SESSION['submit_status'], $_SESSION['submit_mobile'], etc...);
```

But I'm not sure if that gets you anywhere... At least it's not on multiple lines. I will research using wildcards, but you can Google as well as I can :)